# Drupal 6 / No access to admin

Tags: users

There's a Drupal6 website I need to work on for a cliente. However, client does not have access to the admin. They don't remember their user/password.

What's the best way for me to retrieve the admin access besides the "remember password" feature?

Thanks a lot!

Johann

Answer (score 3):

You can reset it directly in the db, if you have access to it?

UPDATE users SET PASS = md5('new_pass') WHERE uid = 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [drush](http://drush.ws/) to do so. Execute 
`drush upwd admin --password=YOURNEWPASSWORD` where `admin` is the username.